# I using cordova-plugin-ibeacon but not working(does'nt find beacons in android)

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, ionic2, ibeacon

here is code

beacon-provider.ts >>

```
 initialise(): any {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {


        IBeacon.enableBluetooth();

        this.delegate = IBeacon.Delegate();

        this.delegate.didRangeBeaconsInRegion()
          .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.events.publish('didRangeBeaconsInRegion', data);
          },
          error => console.error()
          );

        this.region = IBeacon.BeaconRegion('deskBeacon', '24DDF411-8CF1-440C-87CD-E368DAF9C93E');

        IBeacon.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(this.region)
          .then(
          () => {
            resolve(true);
          },
          error => {
            console.error('Failed to begin monitoring: ', error);
            resolve(false);
          }
          );


      } else {
        console.error("This application needs to be running on a device");
        resolve(false);
      }
    });

    return promise;
  }


}
```

home.ts >>

```
export class HomePage {

  beacons: BeaconModel[] = [];
  zone: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform, public beaconProvider: BeaconProvider, public events: Events) {

    this.zone = new NgZone({ enableLongStackTrace: false });

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.beaconProvider.initialise().then((isInitialised) => {
        if (isInitialised) {
          this.listenToBeaconEvents();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  listenToBeaconEvents() {
    this.events.subscribe('didRangeBeaconsInRegion', (data) => {

      this.zone.run(() => {

        this.beacons = [];

        let beaconList = data.beacons;
        beaconList.forEach((beacon) => {
          let beaconObject = new BeaconModel(beacon);
          this.beacons.push(beaconObject);
        });

      });

    });
  }

}
```

In this code, the result of `alert(JSON.stringify(data))` is:

```
{"eventType":"didRangeBeaconslnRegion","region":{"identifier":"desk beacon","uuid":"24DDF411-8CF1-440C-87CD-E368DAF9C93E","typeName":"BeaconRegion"}, "beacons":[]}
```

The field `data.beacons` is empty.

What is the problem?

one more question  i try BLE-central plugin first but,
when i was using BLE-central plugin i get signal but it was not given to me major , minor value if i get this value from advertising ?

Comment: I assume you have edited the data structure shown.  Is the beacons attribute really null or is it an empty array?

Comment: empty array.."beacons":[] like this

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of things that might cause this behavior:

- Verify that Bluetooth is on
- Verify that your app has been granted runtime location permissions needed to detect Bluetooth devices.  Go to Settings -> Apps -> [Your app name] -> Permissions, and make sure you see a Location entry with the switch turned on.
- Verify using an off-the-shelf detector app that your beacon actually is transmitting the identifier you expect.  Try my Locate app here:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en